# JQuery & Tablesorter - Improving performance - update only changed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table which updates every few seconds using an Ajax call. The table was becoming pretty unresponsive when there were a few thousand items in it. The main bottleneck is Tablesorter.js updating the table (reapplying filters, sorting and pagination), which is understandable as it has a lot of data to process.

I have increased performance somewhat by caching the last array of objects returned and then using underscore to compare it to the new one received and only updating the table if there has been a change, in the fashion....

```
var cachedJobData;

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    cache : false,
    url : '/jobs',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(GetNow() + ' got data');
        Items = data;

        if(_.isEqual(Items, cachedJobData)){
            console.log("DATA THE SAME");
        }
        else{
            console.log("DATA DIFFERENT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            rebuildTable();
        }

        cachedJobData = data;
    },
    error: function(Xhr, status, error){
        toastr.error('Error getting job list - ' + error);
    },
    always:function(data){
        if(data.loginResult === 'false'){
            onLoggedOut();
        }
    }
});

function rebuildTable()
{
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(Items, function(index, item){
        tbl_body += makeRow(item);
    }); 
    $("#dbTable tbody").html(tbl_body);

    $("table").trigger("update");
}
```

...this works a lot better than previously, and has greatly improved performance, but I think it could be better.

When Tablesorter has to update a table of 5000ish rows (each with 12 cells) using `$("table").trigger("update")` it tends to take a good few seconds, and the page is unresponsive for this time.

My question is, how can I improve on this? One thing that crossed my mind was to look up each object individually in the current and cached array, and push any differences to another array so I end up with an 'update' array and then apply that to the table by looking up each row by an ID field that I store, then telling Tablesorter to only update those rows. This seems cumbersome though.

I am looking to use Angular eventually, but it's a steep learning curve to achieve the same functionality that Tablesorter gives me in terms of looks, filtering, sorting and pagination.

At the risk of this being labeled as a non-constructive question - any advice?

Comment: Do you need to render all the rows? can't you just render say 200 rows and update the table when user scroll. If you need to put in all the Tablesorter for sorting only then you may think of other approach.

Comment: If you are only adding rows, you could use the [`addRows` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#addrows) instead of `update`. Other than that, I think 5000 rows is a bit excessive to keep in the DOM, especially if you want mobile users on your site.

Comment: No mobile users. It's a workflow tool for internal use for a TV broadcaster, so will only ever run on decent desktops and hosted from a local server room. Also, thousands of items are only shown when users look at historical items and auto refresh is disabled then. I have looked into server side filtering, sorting and paging, with table sorter but I do some extra bits while making a couple of columns involving progress bars that I couldn't work out how to do using the ajaxProcessing option.